# Protected member visible for user

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, protected, access-modifiers

It will be my first question here so please be lenient.

How is this possible:

```
//there is a Form1 class which has a TableAdapter member generated by designer...
partial class Form1
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
         this.SomeTableTableAdapter = new SomeDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.SomeTableTableAdapter();
    }

    private SomeDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.SomeTableTableAdapter SomeTableTableAdapter;
 }

//here is this TableAdapter class
//It has PROTECTED member called "Adapter"
public partial class SomeTableTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component
{
    protected internal global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter Adapter
    {
    }
}

//and in the constructor of Form1 class I can do something like this:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SomeTableTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO (...)";
    }
}
```

How come I get access to protected member since Form1 do not inherit from SomeTableTableAdapter?

Comment: Please use the site features to reply to answers, such as leaving a comment. As this is a Q&A site, answers that aren't in fact answers [will be removed](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Adapter` property is declared as `protected internal`, which means it is accessible to derived classes (`protected`) **and** to classes in the same assembly (`internal`). Since `Form1` is in the same assembly as `SomeTableTableAdapter`, they can access each other's internal members.

Answer (score 4):

`protected internal` means protected OR internal. Access is allowed either from derived classes or from the containing assembly.

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> **protected internal**
>   The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.