# Protected internal class inside a namespace compiles without error

Tags: c#, .net, mono, internal, protected

```
protected internal class foo
{
    //this compiles without any errors
}
```

also

```
internal class bar
{
    public int quix;
    protected internal int zyx;
    //this compiles without any errors
}
```

Are these compiler bugs or my misinterpretation of the standard?

Explanation:

1. Classes can't have protected internal access modifier, only public or internal according to MSDN (Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified).
2. Not all access modifiers can be used by all types or members in all contexts, and in some cases the accessibility of a type member is constrained by the accessibility of its containing type (MSDN). Public should fail. Protected internal is ambiguous for me - internal modifier is not necessary.

**Edit:** The fact that I'm using Mono is unnecessary cause the question was about what standard says and not what MONO does or does not. Maybe I'm coding my own compiler. That's why I quoted MSDN to be precise what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: `protected internal` means `protected` or `internal`

Comment: `protected internal` means `protected` **or** `internal`, no bug here :)

Comment: What is the problem? I don't see any problem with the code.

Comment: [Access Modifiers - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) read the article

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protected member visible for user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915651/protected-member-visible-for-user)

Comment: @user206334 You're not right. The fact that got you on Stackoverflow to ask this question is that you tried to compile this code using the Mono compiler (version, who knows?). Have you tried to compile it using the official C# compiler from Microsoft (CSC)? I did it and I copy-pasted the exact error in my answer. You need to re-think how you ask questions!!!!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I am wondering about a language feature, not a particular compiler which is just an implementation of a standard. According to you, I should ask about C or C++ only and only if I tried to compile using MSVC, which I might not have or it does not work/supported on a platform I'm using to compile. AFAIK, Microsoft C# compiler is not a reference compiler provided with the specification, just a general implementation.

Comment: @user206334 Wrong wrong. If your intention was that, why you put some code comments saying "//this compiles without any errors". **Since you didn't tried it in the official C# compiler, you got this conclusion. Would you came here to ask this question if your compiler would say "NO" to your case? I don't think so.**

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer And what is this official C# compiler? Standard does not mention that. Quoting from: http://www.techstreet.com/cgi-bin/pdf/free/378672/ISO+IEC+23270-2003.pdf "The first widely distributed **implementation of C#** was released by Microsoft in July 2000, as part of its .NET Framework initiative." "Although Microsoft’s implementation of C# relies on CLI for library and runtime support, other implementations of C# need not, provided they support an alternate way of getting at the minimum CLI features required by this C# standard."

Comment: @user206334 Check you question: Are these compiler bugs or my misinterpretation of the standard? <--- WHAT COMPILER.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Any. To rephrase the question: should these considered as bugs of any C# compiler according to C# specification or is it my understanding of a standard wrong and these examples are correct?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, `protected internal` means `protected` **or** `internal` **NOT** `protected` **and** `internal`. No bug here :)

Further information/explanation is on [haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/10/29/what-does-protected-internal-mean.aspx)

In response to your questions:

1. A class within a namespace (and not within another class) can **only be declared as `public` or `internal`**. **HOWEVER**, a class within another class **can be declared as `protected internal`, `private`, etc.**
2. Yes, `protected internal` can be used inside a class whose access modifier is more strict than it's members, see example of a perfectly valid usage below (**note that the class is inside the `Program` class**):

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       }

       private class Foo
       {
           private int priv { get; set; }
           protected internal int protint { get; set; }
           public int pub { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The article talks about protected internal for members of public class, **but** my 1st question is whether protected internal can be specified for a class defined in a _namespace_. My 2nd question is whether public or protected internal can be used inside a class whose access modifier is _more strict_ than its members' access modifiers.

Comment: 1) So this a bug in my compiler
2) Mhm, I see, but this is very strange. I need to think how one can access public member in a nested private class.

Comment: @user206334 1) Hard to say without seeing your **full code**, but I'd doubt it was a compiler issue. 2) One use case for a nested private class with public members is a private implementation of a public interface

Comment: my full code is posted (two separate cases). I understand that, but can those public members be accessed outside of that private class? My line of thought was that if I declare a class private then members would/should be private too.

Comment: @user206334 The private class can only be accessed by the parent class. You are correct, they wouldn't be accessible outside of that scope. It's quite a rare usage to have public members in a private class, other than like I said above to satisfy an interface.

Answer (score 2):

From [`Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

```
protected internal
```

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in
>   which it is declared, **or** from within a derived class in another
>   assembly.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this:

> **protected internal**
>
> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.

So the declaration makes perfect sense, it's just working differently as expected when used outside a class.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, I really doubt that the "protected and internal class" would ever compile *if the class was declared as a member of some namespace*:

C# compiler said:

> Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as
> private, protected, or protected internal

Protected classes will be always nested classes!

### UPDATE

*Since you're trying your code sample in some version of Mono compiler, and you said in your sample code in your question `//this compiles without any errors`, I couldn't understand why you didn't tagged the question for Mono.*

*The standard is the Microsoft C# compiler behavior. If you ask a question about "why something compiles" and **you don't mention that you're not using the official one**, you're just making the assumption that any compiler would compile your code.*

Do you want to know which is the standard? It's -*again*-: **Protected classes will be always nested classes!**

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm talking about. But the compiler I'm using produces no such error which I find strange (it's my 1st question).

Comment: I'm using a particular version of Mono and there is no error produced.

Comment: @user206334 Oh!!! And you expect everyone to know that you're using mono if you don't tag your question for mono!????

Comment: It was a general case about what the STANDARD should say about these cases. It's not about Mono. I could use homebrew DODO compiler for that matter.

Comment: @user206334 Each compiler will implement the STANDARD in their own way. How a convention ensures that any implementer did it well??

Answer (score 0):

Keyword `protected` belongs to inheritance and keyword `internal` belongs to scope.